# How to get xmlschemacomplextype from a qualified name

Tags: c#, xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:complexType name="bwsResponse"> // How to get the xmlschemacomplextype  from the bwsResponse
    <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="errReason" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="errStatus" type="xsd:int"/>
    <xsd:element name="errText" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="transactionId" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

How to get xmlschemacomplextype with name = "bwsResponse" from the Line number 3

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What have you tried? Can you provide some sample code and expected output?

Comment: In above xml my input and output are text below after parsing the string with given input .

Input = bwsResponse(string)
output = xmlschemacomplextype(line 3 )

I was struck here

Comment: In above xml my input and output are text below after parsing the string with given input .

Input = bwsResponse(string)
output = xmlschemacomplextype(line 3 )

I was struck here

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments I concluded that you need the whole element which describes the complex type `bwsResponse`.

To do so, you need to:

Load the xml file into an [`XElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var xml = XElement.Load(@".\path\to\your\file.xml");
```

Filter the descendants by `LocalName` and value of the `name` attribute (those are not the same)

```
var element = xml.Descendants()
    .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "complexType")
    .Where(e => e.Attribute("name") != null && 
            e.Attribute("name").Value == "bwsResponse")
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

And now you can do whatever you want with it.